# Iterate through Xml Nodes in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, parsing

I have a huge xml document and I want to extract only certain data from it. The link to the document is:
https://pastebin.com/mNXWt7dz

I want to parse this xml structure to get values from each `client-mac`, `client-manuf` and `last_signal_dbm` inside each `wireless-client` node of the xml. There are also many `wireless-network` nodes in the document.
I am using following js code:

```
var libxmljs = require("libxmljs");
var fs = require("fs");
var xmlPath =  "./Kismet.netxml";
var fileData = fs.readFileSync(xmlPath, 'ascii');
var xmlDoc = libxmljs.parseXml(fileData);
var children = xmlDoc.root();
console.log(children.get("//wireless-network//wireless-client//client-mac").text());
```

using this code I can only parse value from first `wireless-client` node of the first `wireless-network`. I want values from all the nodes with same names. What should I do? I have already tried other xml parser but none of them seems to work for me.

Comment: BTW—your XML file says it was written with the ISO-8859-1 character encoding but you are reading it with the ASCII character encoding.

Comment: Will that cause any problem in parsing?

Comment: It could because characters in element and attribute [names](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar) do not have to be from the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block. It could also corrupt text and comments. I'm not saying it's your current problem, just that it breaks the fundamental rule of character encodings: reading with the one used for writing.

Comment: Ok! So I should change it to iso. Right?

Comment: It seems that nodejs doesn't support ISO-8859-1 intrinsically.  [read-xml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-xml) might help. Perhaps you can use it with camaro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below snippet. For more info, [check the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/camaro)

the template is xpath like. For example, the below template translates to: Find all nodes at path `//wireless-network/wireless-client`; for each node, extract `client-mac` and put to `mac` field of object, `client-manuf` and put to `manuf` field and so on.

```
const transform = require('camaro')

const xml = `
xml goes here
`
const template = {
    wirelessClients: ['//wireless-network/wireless-client', {
        mac: 'client-mac',
        manuf: 'client-manuf',
        lastSignalDbm: 'snr-info/last_signal_dbm'
    }]
}

const result = transform(xml, template)
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

output

```
{
  "wirelessClients": [
    {
      "lastSignalDbm": "-30",
      "mac": "00:08:22:26:E8:FB",
      "manuf": "Unknown"
    },
    {
      "lastSignalDbm": "-96",
      "mac": "00:62:EC:4A:68:9A",
      "manuf": "Unknown"
    },
    {
      "lastSignalDbm": "-88",
      "mac": "00:A6:CA:F6:4D:3F",
      "manuf": "Unknown"
    },
    {
      "lastSignalDbm": "-90",
      "mac": "00:A6:CA:F6:61:7F",
      "manuf": "Unknown"
    },
    {
      "lastSignalDbm": "-88",
      "mac": "00:D7:8F:FE:EF:20",
      "manuf": "Unknown"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is when there is only when `wireless-network` node in the xml. What if there are more than one `wireless-network` nodes just like in the xml doc I have linked above.

Comment: I just came to know that you are the one developed that package. Great work :). keep it up!